# How to assign a same value to different properties using Object Initializer

Tags: c#, object-initializers

I try to assign a value to two different properties in object initializer and failed.

> In below code i try to assign Expand and Select properies to true. 
>   But i got the error '**The name Select doesnt exist in the current
>   context**'

Here is my code

```
public class MyClass{
public String Title{get;set;}
public String Key{get;set;}
public bool Expand{get;set;}
public bool Select{get;set;}
public bool Editable{get;set;}
}

new MyClass()
  {
   Title = "Murali",
   Key = "MM",                       
   Expand = Select = true
  }
```

Also i need to assign another property Editable based on this two properties

Something like

```
new MyClass()
  {
   Ediatable=(Select && Expand)
  }
```

***How can i do the above logic? Does Object Initializer has a support of it?***

Comment: is noting to worry about, is noting at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to properties of the object you're constructing on the right-hand side of a `=`, i.e., you can only assign to the properties, but not read from them.

Possible solution:

```
var expandAndSelect = true;

var result = new MyClass
{
    Title = "Murali",
    Key = "MM",                       
    Expand = expandAndSelect,
    Select = expandAndSelect,
};
```

and

```
var select = true;
var expand = false;

var result = new MyClass
{
    Expand = expand,
    Select = select,
    Editable = select & expand,
};
```

Comment: Ok. But i was doing this in normal object construction before. Like MyClass obj=new MyClass(); obj.select=true; obj.edit=obj.select; I dont know why it is not there in Object Initializer :(

Comment: Object initializer syntax does not support this. If you want to do this, don't use object initializer syntax.

Comment: The another important fact is i was calling another collection.Contains(key) to get bool value for it. In this case it calls 2 more times :(

Comment: @Murali Just out of curiosity, why do you change from "normal object construction" to object initializer? One possibility is to use normal property assignment on a temp. variable, and then copy the reference from the temp. variable to the "permanent" variable once every propety assignment has succeeded. That's more or less what object initializers do.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, i started using object initializer with lambda expression, something like collection.select(x=>  new MyClass{...}). Now only getting new changes and more properties.